# all the category urls doesn't work. i get 404 error code

Tags: magento2

my system: Magento 2
website: https://homconcept.co.uk/

I don't see any category, and all the category doesn't work.

I tried reindex and clean cache.
but did not work.

https://homconcept.co.uk/catalog/category/view/id/2/
https://homconcept.co.uk/sofas.html
https://homconcept.co.uk/sofas/

none of them work.

can you help me, please?

Comment: can you please check the URLs are generated in URL rewrite?

Comment: yes, i checked, but did not work.